# Vim toggle mappings

Tags: vim

I've set up my mappings as follows:

```
"Set up mappings for LaTeX files 
let b:myEngine=0
let g:myEngineList=["pdflatex","texexec"] "pdflatex or context
function! ToggleEngine()
  if b:myEngine == "pdflatex"
        let b:myEngine = "context"
        execute "imap <F5> :! pdflatex %;<CR>"
        execute "map ;new \begin{document}<CR><CR>\end{document}"
  else
        let b:myEngine = "pdflatex"
        execute "imap <F5> :! context %;<CR>"
        execute "map ;new \starttext<CR><CR>\stoptext"
  fi
  echo "compilation engine:" g:myEngineList[b:myEngine]
endfunction
```

However this isn't behaving at all how I expect; it refuses to remap the keys. Initially no keys are mapped, and once they're mapped, they stay mapped. How do I fix this?

I call ToggleEngine() as follows: `nmap <silent> <F7> :call ToggleSpell()<CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when do you `call ToggleEngine()`?

Suggestion:

```
"Set up mappings for LaTeX files 
let g:myEngineList=["pdflatex","texexec"] "pdflatex or context
function! ToggleEngine()
  if b:myEngine == "pdflatex"
     let b:myEngine = "context"
  else
     let b:myEngine = "pdflatex"
  fi
  execute 'inoremap <F5> :!' . b:myEngine . ' %<cr>'
  echo "spell checking language: " . b:myEngine
endfunction
```

Comment: That is a good solution, except a part of the question I failed to add is that that isn't the only mapping, there are other mappings which don't depend on the name that fail to change. I'm trying out inoremap instead of imap. We'll see.

Comment: Turns out it was the difference between imap and inoremap. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [lh-vim-lib](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib), here is another solution that defines a menu and a command (adding a mapping becomes as simple as calling the command from the mapping).

In your case, it would look like:

```
function! s:getSNR()
  if !exists("s:SNR")
    let s:SNR=matchstr(expand("<sfile>"), "<SNR>\\d\\+_\\zegetSNR$")
  endif
  return s:SNR 
endfunction


function! s:UsePdfLaTeX()
  set makeprg=pdflatex\ $*
  inoremap <buffer> <localleader>new \begin{document}<CR><CR>\end{document}
endfunction

function! s:UseContext()
  set makeprg=context\ $*
  inoremap <buffer> <localleader>new \startext<CR><CR>\stoptext
endfunction

let s:Data = {
      \ "variable": "myengine",
      \ "values": [ 'pdflatex', 'context' ],
      \ "actions": [ function(s:getSNR()."UsePdfLaTeX"), function(s:getSNR()."UseContext") ],
      \ "menu": { "priority": '42.42', "name": '&LaTeX.&Engine'}
      \}
call lh#menu#def_toggle_item(s:Data)
nnoremap <silent> <F7> :Toggle LaTeXEngine<cr>
```

Note: It can be extended to support as many alternatives as you wish.